# Java XML Parsing using SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, saxparser

I have an API.When we request it will produce XML as response data

The below is the API Response for Description field:

```
<parameter>
<name>description</name>
<value>Description Description</value>
</parameter>
```

The below is the code to parse XML File(SAXPraser)

```
public class WorkOrderDataHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public WorkOrderDataHandler() {
        parameterList = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

        contentsOfTheCurrentTag = new StringBuilder();
    }


      public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Details")) {
            ticketData = new TicketInterMediateData();
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("parameter")) {
            parameter = new Parameter();
        }

    }

          public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        int length = contentsOfTheCurrentTag.length();
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            parameter.setName(contentsOfTheCurrentTag.toString().trim());
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            parameter.setValue(contentsOfTheCurrentTag.toString().trim());
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("parameter")) {
            parameterList.add(parameter);
        } 

                 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("parameter")) {
            if ("workorderid".equals(parameter.getName())) {
                ticketData.setIt360ticketid(Integer.parseInt(parameter
                        .getValue().trim()));
            } 

                  else if ("description".equals(parameter.getName())) {
                System.out.println("Handler desc"+ parameter.getValue());//DescriptionDescriptionÂ
            ticketData.setDescription((parameter.getValue()));
                    }

             }
         contentsOfTheCurrentTag.delete(0, length); 
            }


 public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        contentsOfTheCurrentTag.append(ch, start, length);
    }
```

}

**Output**:
When i tried to parse the description field. i am getting the output as **DescriptionDescriptionÂ**

Could anyone please help

Comment: What method are you overriding in DefaultHandler?

Comment: endelement and startelement methods

Comment: public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
   throws SAXException {
  contentsOfTheCurrentTag.append(ch, start, length);
 }

Comment: Remaining fields are properly getting

Comment: Can you post more complete code please?

Comment: Hi Necreaux, I have posted code please check

Comment: What is the encoding of the XML? Does it have a header? This seems like it might be encoding related. Where are you getting the API response text? Are you getting that from logging in the emitter? If not can you verify that is what you are getting in the receiver?